# Openshift Route Configuration to achieve "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url" functionality

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

Is there a way we can achieve the functionality provided by nginx ingress to redirect all API requests to the auth-url before forwarding it to the underlying service (`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url`)using Openshift Ingress controller,
The openshift [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/networking/routes/route-configuration.html) does not explicitly mention anything about it, But wondering if there is an alternate way to achieve this functionality

Comment: This functionality is not supported by OpenShift routes. You can achieve something similar by deploying an oauth proxy (like https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy) in front of your application.

Comment: @larsks gave it a quick read, looks like it integrates directly with OAUTH providers, but  in my case I need to just redirect it to a service which does some pre-processing and appends additional RBAC headers that are application specific